# How to count records by grouping them in cfWheels?

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I have a case where I need to count the number of records grouped by publishing year. I've looked at the documentation, and the net in general, but I can't find what to use.

e.g.

- 2013 = 100 books published
- 2012 = 95 books
- etc..

Using Oracle SQL, this is done using:

```
select date_published, count(*) 
from   publications 
group by date_published 
order by date_published desc
```

I'm just wondering how to translate this to CFWheels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
publications=model("publication").findAll( 
     select="date_published, COUNT(date_published) AS publishCount"
    , group="date_published"
    , order="date_published DESC" );
```

NB, `COUNT()` is a case-sensitive command in wheels.

PS, or you can do what matt says - you could even attach it to the model so you could do publications.getPubCountByYear() etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment, but because I need the formatting I'm posting it as an answer. Can't you write a query just like a regular query in ColdFusion?

```
<cfquery name="getCounts" datasource="myDSN">
select date_published, count(*) 
from publications 
group by date_published 
order by date_published desc
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I can of course but I'm just trying to explore the possibilities of the framework :)